# Aes brute force when part of data known

Tags: aes, keys, cbc, brute-force-attack

I have buffer of 16 bytes that encrypt with AES 128 cbc with IV =000000......(all IV is 0)

I have the encrypted buffer, and I know 7 bytes from 16 bytes before the encryption , I dont know the key .

I want to find out the key.

Is that help to find out the key? Less option than 2^128?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to find the key for AES ECB if I have a list of plaintext and corresponding ciphertext?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63883/18298). If the answer not satisfy you. Lets us know.

Comment: More duplicates: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/58656 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3832 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/41779 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/43148 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48397

Comment: If there was a "dupe hunter" badge then you'd both be receiving it.